# call method before calling controller in every requests in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using **laravel 5** framework. I want to call a method that will call in every user request before calling controller method. How can I do this?

Comment: What should this function do?

Comment: @Tim I want to get subdomain name and do some db query base on it

Comment: Use middleware. And also be wary about doing a database query on _every_ request, as that's going to hammer your database server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write a help function than call it in middleware handler function :

example:

1. add a new file app/Http/Helper.php with function somefunctionYouWillCall
2. in your compoer.json add "files": ["app/Services/Helpers.php"] to aotoload part,then composer dump-autoload.
3. in your middleware handle function  call your function somefunctionYouWillCall(),return $next($request);

check laravel manual how to use middleware